# javafx use node in multiple scenes

Tags: java, javafx, gstreamer

I am creating program using player based on gstreamer and JavaFX. 
From gstreamer I got swing view element (SwingNode). I want to implement full screen functionality. I would like to reuse the same SwingNode in both playing inside app screen and fullscreen mode. General idea is to create two Scenes put SwingNode in one of them and then on mode changing (going from standard to full screen) I will just take this Node from one Scene put it in to another, put this other Scene on Stage and set Stage to fullscreen mode.

Question is there a way to do it? If I just create new Scene with this SwingNode as root I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (...) is already inside a scene-graph and cannot be set as root